# Something is wrong, or I'm not following something - Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.4

Tags: c++, properties

Has anything changed in C++ interpretations, and __property functionality?
Trivial example:

```
class TMyLittleClass
{
private:
TDateTime myDateTime;
protected:
TDateTime getMyDateTime();
void setMyDateTime(TDateTime);
public:
TMyLittleClass(){myDateTime=Now();};
__property TDateTime MyDateTime = {read = getMyDateTime,write=setMyDateTime};
};
```

somewhere further down in the code we make a call:
// it works ok....

```
TDateTime dttTemp;
dttTemp.Val = 0;
```

however, something like this:

```
TMyLittleClass *myClass = new TMyLittleClass();
myClass->MyDateTime.Val =0;
```

triggers compiler protest "[C++ Error] :  expression is not assignable" ... Why?

Compiling with the "Use "classic Borland compiler" setting works ok, compiling with clang causes the problem.Thanks in advance for any hints., as I need to do an upgrade of earlier codes not necessarily of my own making, and there are quite a few such tidbits.
While I understand all the other puzzles, as they are due to syntactic differences between __cplusplus < 201402L and syntaxes of newer versions, this problem is not necessarily clear to me.

Comment: FWIW, `__property` is not standard C++.

Comment: `__property` is not part of the C++ language. According to the embarcadero doc, compiler support is not consistent (see at the bottom of the page): http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Property

Comment: `TMyLittleClass myClass = new TMyLittleClass();` isn't legal. `new TMyLittleClass()` creates a pointer to `TMyLittleClass`, but `TMyLittleClass myClass` is an object, not a pointer.

Comment: @PeteBecker Of course you are right. Correctly it should be TMyLittleClass *myClass = new TMyLittleClass(); This can be seen by the "->" rather than the "." used. The problem, however, is not in the correctness of writing *myClass, but in the inability to write to "myClass->MyDateTime.Val =0;" Reading "myClass->MyDateTime.Val =0" is of course possible. In the embarcadero documentation on the differences between Clang-enh. C++ Compilers and Prev-Gen C++ Comp. I didn't see any mention that __property should differ on the level of this interpretation.